# Update a database table "user" in PHP called from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need to update a database table using javascript in my html page , what i need is when loading this page i want to update the date in database every 30 sec

```js
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  updatetime()   // i want to call the php function from java
  },30000);
```

```css
  
<?php 
  
function updatetime(){
    $query="UPDATE user SET time='......";  // here i update the database
    $result=mysql_query($query);
   }

?>
```

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use PDO / MySQLi instead

Comment: i tried to put update time in php like this <script> <?php updatetime() ?> </script> but i only works for 1 time and didnt execute every 30 sec , and i tried to put inside this an alert to show if the interval is running , the results was that the alert is running every 30 sec but the update function is running the first time .

Comment: And you completely mixed up client-side & server-side scripts. Use AJAX to call server-side scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot call php function fron script like that. Use ajax for that

script

```
 var timer = setInterval(function(){
   updatetime()   // i want to call the php function from java
 },30000);

function updatetime(){
    $.ajax({
         url:"filename.php",
         type:"POST",
         successs: function(data) {

         }
    });
 }
```

Create a file called `filename.php` and add this code in that function,

```
<?php
    $query="UPDATE user SET time='......";  // here i update the database
    $result=mysql_query($query);
?>
```

As mentioned by `raptor`, stop using `mysql_*` use `mysqli_*` or `pdo` instad.

Comment: 10x a lot this solution is perfect it works 100% thanks

Comment: Glad i could help you:)

Comment: niranjan i need to ask another question , i have a number of html pages and i need to put that script code in all pages , i can include it ? like php